# Inconsistent pip behavior with package installation and uninstallation

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, virtualenvwrapper

In a fresh console, without issuing any other command first,

```
pip freeze
```

showed me I've installed virtualenvwrapper 3.2. I wanted to upgrade it to the latest version, so I issued

```
pip install -U virtualenvwrapper
```

pip told me the upgrade was successful, which in fact it just installed as a separate version somewhere else:

```
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper-3.6-py2.6-nspkg.pth
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper-3.6-py2.6.egg-info
```

So when I do pip freeze again, I still see I've got 3.2 (no sign of 3.6), and this 3.2 version lives here:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper-3.2-py2.7-nspkg.pth
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper-3.2-py2.7.egg-info
```

So I wanted to remove the 3.6 version installed with pip, by doing

```
pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper
```

However, now, **pip wants to uninstall the 3.2 version which lives with Python 2.7**! So why pip didn't upgrade the right virtualenvwrapper in the first place?

In addition, when I do

```
workon some_env
```

This apparently uses the 3.2 version of virtualenvwrapper, so what is going on?

Comment: I think you got your `pip` binaries confused. A `pip` for Python 2.7 will *never* install into a Python 2.6 installation. Did you use `sudo` when running `pip install` but not for the `freeze` command??

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I think you may be right about this, so I just managed to uninstall the virtualenvwrapper 3.6 that was installed under Python 2.6. But now I see this warning: `UserWarning: Module pkg_resources was already imported from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.pyc, but /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages is being added to sys.path from pkg_resources import load_entry_point` when I use `pip` (without `sudo`).